# J2ME : How to get SDCard's available Free Space

Tags: java-me, sd-card

I am building J2ME application, where I want to get size of available free space on SDCard and on Phone internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileConnection fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///SDCard/");

long total = fc.totalSize();

long used = fc.usedSize();

long free = total - used;
```